# Having issues with the flows whenever they run in Asynchronous mode

Tags: visual-workflow, automation, asynchronous

While working on establishing a record trigger flow, my objective was to synchronize and manage specific fields related to Skills and Certifications between the PSA system and the Skill object in the Field Service system. It is important to note that the Skill object in the Field Service system is classified as a Setup object, while the Skill and Certifications object is considered a non-setup object.

I encountered a DML Exception error due to the difference between setup and non-setup objects. To overcome this issue, I executed the flow in an Asynchronous path, but it came with certain drawbacks. For instance, I could not update the setup object or use both the Create and Update elements simultaneously.

The actual use case is as follows:

1. When a PSA Skill/Certification record (pse__Skill__c) is created, a corresponding Field Service Skill should be created and linked to the PSA Skill/Certification.
2. When a PSA Skill/Certification record (pse__Skill__c) is updated, the related Field Service Skill should be updated.
3. When a PSA Skill/Certification record (pse__Skill__c) is deleted, the related Field Service Skill should be deleted.
4. Field Service Skills should never be directly created, edited, or deleted.

To address this, I developed a Record trigger flow that creates the Field Service Skill when a Skill/Certification is created in PSA. The creation process is functioning properly without any issues. However, the challenge lies in the requirement to also update the newly created skill in the PSA Skill/Certificate, which should reflect the changes in Field Service.

To accomplish this, I need to store the record ID created in the flow. Unfortunately, the Asynchronous path does not allow me to store the record ID in the update element. Instead, I am storing the record ID created in a new text field on the PSA Skill/Certificate.

*Approach 1**: Initially, I attempted to create a sub-flow and invoke it from the main flow. However, this approach resulted in a DML error. Consequently, I decided to try a different approach by creating a second flow specifically for the update process. Unfortunately, I encountered a limitation because the Field Service Skill object cannot be used as a triggering object, as it is a Setup object. As a workaround, I used the PSA Skill/Certification object itself as the triggering object. I utilized a "get element" to retrieve all the records from FS Skills and update the required skill ID in the newly created text field in the PSA Skill object to store the record ID from the first flow, which is responsible for creating new records in both PSA and FS.

The first flow, which handles creation, needs to run first, followed by the second flow, which updates the ID of the record created in the first flow. To achieve this, I introduced a checkbox in the first flow. Only when this checkbox is set to true, the second flow runs. However, this approach did not function as expected, especially when editing the details of an already created record.

**Approach 2** : The second approach also involves running the first flow followed by the second one. I attempted to change the "Trigger Order" to 1 for the first flow and 2 for the second flow. In the "Flow Trigger Explorer," the order appeared correct, with priority given to the first flow. However, this solution also failed to work as expected. It was successful in creating records, but struggled to store the record ID of the created record.

I would greatly appreciate any tips or assistance regarding this matter.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Your verbal description (_this approach did not function as expected_, _struggled to store the record ID_) is a good first step but it's not sufficient. Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful

Comment: so basically, DML occurs on PSAS/C and you need to do DML(create) on setup object FSS and then update the triggering PSAS/C with the Id of the FSS?  Seems like calling invocable apex that delegates the FSS CRUD + PSAS/C to async (future/queueable) would do the trick